# Can I import a list of invoices into Quickbooks Desktop as a CSV or Excel file?

Tags: quickbooks

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing data for a bunch of sales invoices, which I exported from another system. I want to import this to QB Desktop Pro. I'm a bit confused about IIF files vs. CSV/Excel files. I know what the latter are. I don't know what IIF files are, aside from the fact that they are tab-limited files that seem to have been invented by Intuit.

I have QB Desktop Pro. Can I import this Excel file "as is" without paying for a third-party converter app? I found [this article](https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-us/manage-invoices/import-multiple-invoices-at-once/00/185742) but it seems to apply to QB Online only. It's frankly bewildering that QB Online and QB Desktop are so different.

Answer (score -1):

I'm unaware of any ability to import into QB Desktop directly from an Excel file "as is" however, you can save properly formatted data from excel as a CSV file and import that into QBDT without a third party tool. The process is tricky, not particularly well documented, and not for the faint of heart, though.

Good Luck.